# HTML5 draggable's drop event not getting triggered intermittently due to DOM manipulation in dragover event

Tags: javascript, html, svg, draggable

I am using html5 'draggable' attribute to drag 2 elements within a container and svg line to connect the two.
Once connected, Dragging the first Div should redraw the connecting svg line (i do on dragover event by calling 'handleDragOver' function). But If you drag the first div faster, drop event is not triggered and the div maintains it's original place while the line gets drawn.

```
function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    //Some code doing DOM computation and manipulation
    }
    return false;
    //e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}
```

How can I ensure that drop event gets triggered every time.

Please note:

1. I can't use any framework, just plain javascript
2. I can't not redraw line while dragging.
3. drag functionality works fine when I'm not doing any computation/redrawing in 'handleDragOver'

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanbhasker/3yx9ds4m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sejoker/d4vs9fgs/1/
following changes:

- line manipulation moved from dragover's handler to handleDrop, redraw line once during drag'n'drop operation
- calling moveLine in setTimeout seems to improve usability (optional)
- minor changes in moveLine function to connect draggable elements properly (optional)

  ```
  function handleDrop(e) {
  console.log('enter Drop');
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
  }
  var offset = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text').split(',');
   dragSrcEl.style.left = (e.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
   dragSrcEl.style.top = (e.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';

   setTimeout(function(){
      var elem = svgLine.aLine;
      if (elem !== null) {
          var x = e.clientX - svgLine.left,
              y = e.clientY - svgLine.top;
          moveLine(x, y, elem, offset[2]);
      }            
   }, 50)
  ```